# can an EC2 instance decline an autoscale termination?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

Is there a way for an EC2 instance in an autoscaling group to decline a scale-down termination request?  I'm in a situation with highly dynamic load...and I don't want to terminate an instance that's in the first part of its charging hour. Even with the autoscale policy losestToNextInstanceHour I see cases where an instance is terminated that has 40 minutes left on its hour...and within that 40 minutes the load increases again.

So, I want my instances to be able to "thanks for asking me to terminate but I decline".   Is this possible?

Comment: This might be helpful, depending on your use case: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/auto-scaling-delay-termination/

Comment: Thats almost what I want.   It would allow me to get the remaining hour's worth of work out of the instance which is good but all other AutoScaling is on hold while an instance is in terminate::wait.

When I did manual autoscaling we checked a condition to decide if we should downscale but then skipped the downscale if no instances were within 5 minutes of their hour boundary.  Still trying to figure a way to do the same using AutoScaling / CloudWatch.

Comment: You could handle this in a number of ways (including the suggestion by Anthony above).  Other options include increasing the cool down time on your ASG, and turning on termination protection on the instance for the first hour of its life.  You could have a policy in the IAM role that allows for the instance to modify its own instance protection and have a task/script that kicks off at boot time that turns it on and places a timestamp somewhere.  You also have a cronjob or something that runs an hour later and based upon the previously recorded timestamp, turns instance protection off, etc..

Answer (score 0):

You could change instance protection to "Protect From Scale In" for the instances you want reject scale-in termination. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/AutoScalingBehavior.InstanceTermination.html#instance-protection

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You can select an instance in Autoscaling group and choose Protect From Scale in. 
It can be easily done via AWS Console. Go to ASG then instances then select the instances you want to protect then from actions just above the select box choose the option.

You can also do it via: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/as-instance-termination.html#instance-protection

You can even edit settings in ASG and change settings according to lifetime of an instance: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/as-instance-termination.html#custom-termination-policy